# Will console.log prevent garbage collection?

Tags: javascript

If I have an object that would normally be garbage collected, but has been logged to the console, will it still be eligible for garbage collection?

```
(function(){
  var o = { foo: {} }; 
  console.log(o);
}())

// Can o be collected?
```

If yes, are there any circumstances where writing to the console (using any of its methods) can affect eligibility for garbage collection?

**Edit: I dont believe it will affect eligibility for collection based on watching the heap in Chrome dev tools. But will any category of writing to the console do so?**

Comment: Chrome sometimes adds a note to logged objects, something like "evaluated upon first expansion". This suggests that the object might have been GCd in the meantime. But it could also just refer to modifications.

Comment: @Thomas I'm pretty sure it's referring to modifications.

Answer (score 6):

If you log an object to the console it can not be garbage collected.

You can verify this by entering in the chrome console:

```
var Foo = function() {};
console.log(new Foo());
```

Go to “Profiles” and “Take Heap Snapshot”. This will do a garbage collection automatically. Search for class “Foo”. There will be a `1` in column “Objects count“.

Comment: My own experiments came to the opposite conclusion by looking at the heap allocated memory. Steps to repro: open dev tools, force a garbage collection, run your code, force a garbage collection. My tests showed the allocated memory was freed. I could however be misguided.

Comment: Did you take a heap snapshot after the last garbage collection?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome 41.0.2272.76 (64-bit) on Linux. What is your Chrome version?

Comment: @hhelwich '“Take Heap Snapshot”. This will do a garbage collection automatically' using Chrome `Version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)` this statement doesn't seem to be true (anymore). I took a Heap snapshot, there were objects present that I believed should have been GC'ed, I manually 'Collected garbage' and took another heap snapshot and they vanished.