# React-Redux: Loosing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, apollo

So, I'm having an issue with redux not keeping state of a 'token' value.
Upon vising the app you are directed to a login page. Submitting your login details returns an auth token, which assigns the value of the returned token value to the variable token, adds token to props, and then redirects you to the main part of the app '/'.

If I immediately return to the login page '/login' the token disappears from props, causing a user to have to re-login again.

What is the issue here?

app.js

```html
render(
  <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
    { /* Tell the Router to use our enhanced history */ }
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={PhotoGrid} />
        <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}></Route>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginUser}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```html
function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
    token: state.token[0]
  };
}
```

Root reducer (index.js)

```html
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import client from '../apolloClient';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'; // we need this for react-router
import tokenDetails from './tokenDetails';
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  token: tokenDetails,
  routing: routerReducer,
  apollo: client.reducer(),
});

export default rootReducer;
```

tokenDetails.js

```html
var tokenDetails = function(state, action) {

  if (state === undefined) {
    state = [];
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Graphcool_Token':
      const newState = [action.payload];
      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default tokenDetails;
```

actionCreator,js

```html
export function authToken(token) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'Graphcool_Token',
      payload: token
    });
  } 
}
```

LoginUser.js

```html
  signinUser: function(emailID, passwordID) {

    const email = emailID;
    const password = passwordID;

    this.props.client.mutate({
      mutation: signinUser_Mutation,
      variables: {
        email,
        password,
      },
      options: {
        cachePolicy: 'offline-critical', 
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
      },
    })
    .then(this.updateStateLoginDetails)
    .catch(this.handleSubmitError);
  },

  updateStateLoginDetails: function({data}) {
    this.props.authToken(data.signinUser.token);
    this.context.router.push('/');
  },

  handleSubmitError: function(err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  },

  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.signinUser(this.refs.email.value, this.refs.password.value);
    this.refs.loginForm.reset();
    this.refs.email.focus();
  },
  render: function() {
  }
```

store.js

```html
const middlewares = [thunk, client.middleware()];

const enhancers = compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),

    (typeof window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ !== 'undefined' || process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : (f) => f,
    autoRehydrate(),
);

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  {}, // initial state
  enhancers
);

// begin periodically persisting the store
persistStore(store, {storage: localForage});

export const history = syncHistoryWithStore(
  browserHistory, 
  store
);

if(module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./reducers/', () => {
    const nextRootReducer = require('./reducers/index').default;
    store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
  });
}

export default store;
```

Comment: it looks a bit buggy. `token: state.token[0]` assumes there is one element always. The initial state is an empty array.

Comment: @vijayst So how do I best handle the assignment, and injecting into props, of a token value that can only be ascertained after having logged in?

Comment: I think it works, will give an undefined. But will be nice to have a state which is initialised to `['']` - array with an empty string. token seems to be part of an object. I am wondering if it is garbage collected :) Maybe, a console.log can help test for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839652/will-console-log-prevent-garbage-collection

Comment: @vijayst Ok so I've manged to ascertain that if a hard browser reload of any of the Route paths is done, the store gets destroyed and `state === undefined` in tokenDetails.js gets triggered. thus resetting state back to `state = {}`. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Store the token in localStorage instead of Redux.