# Chrome Speech Synthesis: No longer outputting sound

Tags: javascript, audio, w3c

I have been using the Text To Speech described by [W3C spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#utterance-attributes) for an app.

```
    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('我要看菜单');
    utterance.lang = "zh-cmn";
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
```

The native audio files were playing for a while but then audio just suddenly stopped. I am aware of the character limit per request (I think like [< 200-300 chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947730/chrome-speech-synthesis-with-longer-texts))... I'm only getting Speech for about 5 characters. So I know length per request is not the issue.

The next issue I thought is # requests. Since I am testing this functionality in an app, I've had to make several requests for audio before it suddenly stopped. I have read through the specs and it doesn't specify anywhere the max requests per day for any length of string.

This is a **critical** component of my app and need to ensure that audio just doesn't stop returning one day randomly for users.

Can anyone offer some info on why audio files suddenly stopped playing?